# Adding “Unblock the user” option in Views Bulk Operations field

Tags: views

I have created a user based view and I used the Views Bulk Operations module, but I don't see *Unblock user* or something like that. I also want to show tree-based roles in the bulk operation options list.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is the code to add 'Unblock the user' option in Views Bulk Operations field.

```
/**
* Implements hook_action_info().
*/
function mymodule_action_info() {
return array(
'mymodule_unblock_user_action' => array(
'label' => t('Unblock the user'),
'type' => 'user',
'configurable' => FALSE,
'triggers' => array('any'),
 ),
 );
}

/**
 * Unblocks a user, defaulting to the current user.
  *
 * @ingroup actions
 */
 function mymodule_unblock_user_action($entity, $context = array()) {
 // First priority: If there is a $entity->uid, unblock that user.
 // This is most likely a user object or the author if a node or comment.
 if (isset($entity->uid)) {
 $uid = $entity->uid;
    }
   // Otherwise get user ID from the context.
 elseif (isset($context['uid'])) {
  $uid = $context['uid'];
  }
 $account = user_load($uid);
  $account = user_save($account, array('status' => 1));
 watchdog('action', 'Unblocked user %name.', array('%name' => $account->name));
    }
```

Taken answer from [This](http://www.tekritisoftware.com/add-unblock-user-option-views-bulk-operations-field) Link.

Answer (score 3):

In drupal 7-

We need a **Rules module**, after enable Rules module and Rules UI go to

1- **Configuration -> Workflow-> Rules-> Component-> Add Component**

In **Component plugin** dropdown-> select **Action Set**
then add next page 
Fill the mandatory field Name as (Ex: Unblock user)

2- Select **Data type** from list **User** ---Label **Unblock user** ---machine name **unblock_user** -- usage **parameter**

3- In **setting** option you can set **Permission** roles wise.

then click on **continue** button
then click on **Add Action Link**

4- then Select the action to add **User ->Unblock User**

5- Select **Data Selector** -> **unblock-user** and Save

6- Now go to- **Views** Page add field **Bulk operations** there will be present **Unblock user** option

for reference - [Add Unblock user option by rules in views and set permission](http://sumitkumarprajapati.blogspot.in/2016/02/adding-unblock-user-option-in-views.html)